# how to apply the remote yaml?

Tags: kubernetes, ansible

I would like to apply the ingress https://projectcontour.io/ to my kubernetes cluster with ansible community.kubernetes.k8s.

The example on https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/kubernetes/k8s_module.html shows me how to apply local files, for instance

```
- name: Create a Deployment by reading the definition from a local file
  community.kubernetes.k8s:
    state: present
    src: /testing/deployment.yml
```

However I could not find the example with remote file.

With `kubectl` the deployment of contour ingress can be done as follow:

```
kubectl apply -f https://projectcontour.io/quickstart/contour.yaml
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I read the docs, I don't see an option to do that.
You could download the file first, then apply it.

```yaml
- name: retrieve file
  get_url:
    url: https://projectcontour.io/quickstart/contour.yaml
    dest: /testing/contour.yaml
  register: download_contour

- name: create deployment
  k8s:
    src: /testing/deployment.yml
  when: download_contour.changed
```

Comment: One more question, is it going to download on my local computer? Do I have to create a folder first?

Comment: It will download on the target machine. If you want the command to be executed on the local machine, look at this example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18900236/run-command-on-the-ansible-host

Comment: The folder has to exist. I assume that was already done. You can use this example to create a folder beforehand: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/file_module.html