# How would I dynamically change a windows hostname with Ansible in GCP

Tags: windows, google-cloud-platform, ansible, hostname

Here's the situation: We're using ansible to make a bunch of changes to newly deployed VMs in GCP. One of those changes is to update the hostname.

GCP has a requirement that the first character in a hostname must be a letter. So, lets say our hostnames in GCP are PC1000-blah-blah. With Ansible, I want to dynamically pull that hostname (PC1000-blah-blah) and change it do 1000-blah-blah, dropping the "PC".

Now, I can do this on a VM by VM basis with the ansible.windows.win_hostname plugin: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/windows/win_hostname_module.html

But I haven't been able to figure out how to run my playbook against a group of VMs, where it's smart enough to see the current hostname (with PC) and drop the PC on each.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Your strategy will fail. Even if Ansible changes the hostname to **1000-blah-blah**, you will break DNS, and cause DHCP errors. VM hostnames must conform to RFC 1035. This regex defines allowed hostnames: **[a-z]([-a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9])?**.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`ansible-module-gce-facts`](https://github.com/br0ziliy/ansible-module-gce-facts) to gather information about an instance. In Ansible playbook, on can use `hosts: 127.0.0.1` and `connection:local` to run eg. `gcloud` in a [local shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18900236/run-command-on-the-ansible-host).

And setting the `hostname` can also be done with [metadata](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/metadata/default-metadata-values). For Windows VM there are further possibilities to automate an instance (if setting the metadata `hostname` should not suffice):

> `windows-startup-script-url`, `windows-startup-script-cmd`, `windows-startup-script-bat`, `windows-startup-script-ps1`, `sysprep-specialize-script-url`, `sysprep-specialize-script-cmd`, `sysprep-specialize-script-bat`, and `sysprep-specialize-script-ps1`.

Here's an example `sysprep-specialize-script-ps1`: [`instance_setup.ps1`](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/compute-image-windows/blob/master/sysprep/instance_setup.ps1)... in particular [`function Change-InstanceName`](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/compute-image-windows/blob/5b85ba5f184e259b0b0291f4b314beaa504c0d95/sysprep/instance_setup.ps1#L70) should not only be in the sys-prep script, but should run as `windows-startup-script-ps1`, so that the installation will always reflect the *current host-name* from the metadata:

```
function Change-InstanceName {
  <#
    .SYNOPSIS
      Changes the machine name for GCE Instance
    .DESCRIPTION
      If metadata server is reachable get the instance name for the machine and
      rename.
  #>

  Write-Log 'Getting hostname from metadata server.'

  if ((Get-CimInstance Win32_BIOS).Manufacturer -cne 'Google') {
    if (-not (Test-Connection -Count 1 metadata.google.internal -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)) {
      Write-Log 'Not running in a Google Compute Engine VM.' -error
      return
    }
  }

  $count = 1
  do {
    $hostname_parts = (Get-Metadata -property 'hostname') -split '\.'
    if ($hostname_parts.Length -le 1) {
      Write-Log "Waiting for metadata server, attempt $count."
      Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
    }
    if ($count++ -ge 60) {
      Write-Log 'There is likely a problem with the network.' -error
      return
    }
  }
  while ($hostname_parts.Length -le 1)

  $new_hostname = $hostname_parts[0]
  # Change computer name to match GCE hostname.
  # This will take effect after reboot.
  try {
    (Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystem).Rename($new_hostname)
    Write-Log "Renamed from $global:hostname to $new_hostname."
    $global:hostname = $new_hostname
  }
  catch {
    Write-Log 'Unable to change hostname.'
    Write-LogError
  }
}
```

So you probably won't change the host-name with ansible ...but still can edit the meta-data, in order to change the `hostname` and to provide a windows sys-prep or startup script - and then let these instances apply the meta-data by themselves with eg. Powershell (then reboot to apply the new host-name).

One could just run `(Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystem).Rename($new_hostname)` on each instance and/or remove the leading `PC` while doing so and then reboot - but it is nevertheless recommend, to let a script pick up and apply the meta-data (which is self-managed). Well, it might make sense to only reboot when the host-name actually has changed (the example above is rather a sys-prep script, which therefore assumes a reboot/shutdown after it ran).

This would at least give you the current hostname, according to meta-data (while set):

```
gcloud compute instances describe instance-1 --zone europe-west3-c --format="value(metadata.items.hostname)"
```

Comment: Hi Martin, thanks for the detailed response. I attempted to rename using a .ps1 script on startup:

`Rename-Computer -ComputerName $env:COMPUTERNAME -NewName ($env:COMPUTERNAME -replace "pc","") -LocalCredential local\admin`

But the "Rename-Computer" command doesn't allow a password, so the script fails as unauthorized during startup. Maybe there's another way to so this at startup so it drops the 'PC'?