# How to check if the Virtual Machines are not accessible on port 8080

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-vpc

In GCP how can we check if the compute engines are not accessible on port 8080. Is there any API where we can check and validate this scenario

Comment: SSH into your instance and run this command to get an overview: netstat -pltn

Comment: You can also use port scanning https://linuxhint.com/port_scan_linux/

Comment: @danyL Thanks for the reply....can we get these info from cloud asset inventory

Comment: Do you want to use Connectivity test from Network Intelligence Center? https://cloud.google.com/network-intelligence-center/docs/connectivity-tests/reference/networkmanagement/rest/v1/projects.locations.global.connectivityTests

Comment: You can perform a telnet to the machine IP:PORT or use connectivity test.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere but that requires me to login to the instance to check that right which will be a slow process .....since my list is very big

Comment: Is the port 8080 exposed externally? Why do you need to log into the VM to check the port exposure?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Then how an we check that....

Comment: Let me know from where do you want to test the accessibility. From public internet? Do you have a public IP, do you have a load balancer ?

Comment: Not sure from cloud asset but there is another product that can analyze http traffic https://cloud.google.com/security-command-center/docs/concepts-vulnerabilities-findings#firewall-findings

Answer (score 1):

**There are many ways of doing what you want** - however there are a few factors that I don't know so this answer may sound a bit generic in a few places.

1. Scenario 1 - instances have to be accessible from the Internet

- check if the firewall settings allow incoming traffic to your instances on port 8080 (you can use [cloud console](https://console.cloud.google.com/networking/firewalls/list) or [`gcloud`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/firewall-rules/list)).
- if there isn't such a rule you have to create one - it's best to [label your instances](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/add-remove-network-tags#source_filters_for_ingress_firewall_rules) and [create a proper rule](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls).
- now you can actually check if there's anything running on port 8080 - if this is a web app / API you can just use `curl host.ip:port 2> errors.log`.

You mentioned you have a lot of instances to check then some script would be handy - have a look at [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1521498/12257250) how to create one that will read the addressess from the file.

If you want to do it like a pro use Ansible - here's a [useful answer](https://devops.stackexchange.com/a/1664) that will be helpful for this.

2. Scenario 2 - instances are not available from the Internet

- you need to run the mentioned instance checking script from within your VPC your instances are in. Create a new VM for this purpose and run the script from there. If your instances are spread across many VPC's you need to create a VM in each of them and run the script.

And you can automate this with Ansible - even create/test instances & delete VM's. This may sound like an overkill but everything on how often you need to run those tests and on the number of VM's you need to test.

---

**Also there's a question of testing if the ports are open from inside the insances.**

- if they are running Linux then [dany L's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70507458/how-to-check-if-the-virtual-machines-are-not-accessible-on-port-8080#comment124638598_70507458) is a good one. But since you have to repeat that many-many times Ansible may again be a good way to do this - have a look at another answer describing [how to run a command on the target host](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18907395/12257250).
- if they are running Windows then it's more complicated but you can use [`netsh firewall` command](https://9to5it.com/windows-firewall-is-my-port-being-blocked/) - and again - using Ansible is possible.